# Maya Python How to access polyCube

Tags: python, graphics, maya, maya-api

I couldn't find any answer so I fought I ask here.

I'm working on a poly generator tool in which I want to set Values of the height and width of a cube.

My problem is that I don't know how to get the name of the construction history e.g. 'polyCube1'.
This is where I'm stuck:

```
def CreateSmoothedCube(user_chosen_name, external_input):
            cmds.polyCube(name=user_chosen_name)
            var = """get History Name here""" 
            cmds.setAttr("var.height", external_input)
```

Thanks to anyone looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example :

```
def CreateSmoothedCube(user_chosen_name='pCube1', height=1):
    if not cmds.objExists(user_chosen_name)
        cub = cmds.polyCube(name=user_chosen_name, h=height)
        var = cub[1]
    else:
        var = [i for i in cmds.listHistory(user_chosen_name) if cmds.nodeType(user_chosen_name)=='polyCube']
        cmds.setAttr("{}.height".format(var[0]), height)
    return [user_chosen_name, var]
```

Or this more simple version :

```
def CreateSmoothedCube(user_chosen_name, **kwargs):
    cub = cmds.polyCube(name=user_chosen_name, **kwargs)
    return cub

cub = CreateSmoothedCube('my_name', h=5, w=10)
print(cub)
```